# Given two of three items, return the missing item

Tags: python, set, iteration

The set of items is {0,1,2} (indices of a list of length 3), and given two of these, I need to know the third. Right now I have:

```
def missingint(i,j):
    return list(set([0,1,2]) - set([i,j]))[0]
```

which seems very heavy-handed. I need an integer back so that I can then call `mylist[k]`.

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, if you are looking for solution for the [0,1,2] set, then you can simply use:

```
def missingint(i,j):
    return 3-i-j
```

it is easy to check, that it works (and obviously - it is very simple and efficient)

```
missingint(0,1) == 2
missingint(1,0) == 2
missingint(0,2) == 1
missingint(2,0) == 1
missingint(1,2) == 0
missingint(2,1) == 0
```

To my best knowledge, there is no simplier solution in python

In **general case**, it also works for any predefined set, if you want to find **exactly one** missing value

```
def missingint(whole_list , other_values):
    return sum( whole_list ) - sum( other_values )
```

for for example for the [0,3,13,24] set you could declare

```
def missingint(i,j,k):
    return 40-i-j-k
```

etc.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
x=[1,4,5,6]
y=[1,4,6]
[i for i in x if i not in y]
```

**edit:** also if you're sure there's only one item missing you can do this:

```
[i for i in x if i not in y][0]
```

to get the int out of the list

Comment: That works, but I'm not sure it's easier than the one I proposed. However, this syntax is something I have been trying to remember to use.